# Proper way to map combo box lines to their corresponding strategy objects?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have a situation that is pretty simple, and I'd like to know the ideal way to do it.

I have a combo box.  Each line of the combo box corresponds to a particular strategy object.

What is the proper way to map the combo box lines to the strategy object.

The way I was doing it seems overly complicated, and I'm pretty much guaranteed there is a simple standard way to do this.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I had the data in a Dictionary, where the string was the text for the combobox, and the object was the strategy...  But this isn't ordered...  And I just know there is some extremely simple way to do it.

SOLUTION:
I used this solution, not feeling comfortable putting presentation logic in the data classes:

```
private partial class HtmlTransformState : AbstractHtmlEditFormState
{
private Dictionary<string, ITransformStrategy> strategies = new Dictionary<string, ITransformStrategy>() 
{ 
    { "Simple URL", new TransformStrategy<SimpleUrlCodeExtractor>() }, 
    { "Overview", new TransformStrategy<OverviewCodeExtractor>() },  
    { "Video List", new TransformStrategy<VideoListCodeExtractor>() }, 
    { "Video List No MbORKb", new TransformStrategy<VideoListNoMBOrKBAndNoLinksAllowedCodeExtractor>() },
    { "Blue Mountain 2007", new TransformStrategy<BlueMountain2007CodeExtractor>() },
    { "Four Gates", new TransformStrategy<FourGatesCodeExtractor>() },
    { "General", new TransformStrategy<GeneralCodeExtractor>() }
};
public override void DrawForm()
{
    // ...
    ParentForm.cmboTransformStrategy.DataSource = new BindingSource(strategies, null);
    ParentForm.cmboTransformStrategy.DisplayMember = "Key";
    ParentForm.cmboTransformStrategy.ValueMember = "Value";
}

public override IEnumerable<string> ProcessHtml(string urlPath)
{
    ITransformStrategy transformStrategy = (ITransformStrategy)ParentForm.cmboTransformStrategy.SelectedValue;

    // Do some stuff with 'transformStrategy'
}
```

}

Comment: are you using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx ?

Comment: you should look at my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
public class Strategy
{
    private string _name = "default";
    public string Name
    {
         get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public Strategy(string name)
{
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

Then in form load (you need to have a combo box on that form):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Strategy> ls = new List<Strategy>();
    ls.Add(new Strategy("First"));
    ls.Add(new Strategy("Second"));
    ls.Add(new Strategy("Third"));

    comboBox1.DataSource = ls;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

Comment: I am uncomfortable putting presentation information in the data classes...  It seems to confuse the separation of concerns.  Plus, who is to say the Strategy objects are going to know exactly how I want them to be formatted on the comboBox?

Comment: Point taken. In some cases I use the "partial" feature of C# to separate logic. Data still is in the same class but in 2 files, one with the DB access layer (for instance) and the other with the presentation stuff. There are many ways to organize a hierarchy and I'm not saying one way is better than other; whatever works and follows the KISS principle I like :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event on the combobox and select the corresponding dictionary entry

found that, [Bind a Dictionary to a ComboBox](http://snipplr.com/view/8502/bind-a-dictionary-to-a-combobox/) see below for a working example(at least on the original vb.net code that I wrote)

**Vb.net converted into C#, you will have to manage the handle yourself**

```
public class Form1
{

private Dictionary<int, myDic> dict = new Dictionary<int, myDic>();

private void  // ERROR: Handles clauses are not supported in C#
ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    KeyValuePair<int, myDic> curItem = (KeyValuePair<int, myDic>)ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(curItem.Value.myvalue);
}

private void  // ERROR: Handles clauses are not supported in C#
Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    myDic d = default(myDic);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        d = new myDic();
        d.myKey = i.ToString;
        d.myvalue = Strings.Chr(65 + i);
        dict.Add(d.GetHashCode, d);
    }
    ComboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "value";
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
}
}

class myDic
{
public string myKey;
public string myvalue;

public override string tostring()
{
    return myvalue;
}
}
```

Comment: but how can you use it when the data isn't ordered?  Like with a Dictionary.  This is the way I WAS doing it, but it required going through hoops with a List<>.

Comment: If I could have a List<TextStrategyPair> that would be ideal.  Or and OrderedDictionary<string, object>...

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I will have to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Override ToString for your strategy object. After that you can insert your strategy objects directly in the combo box.

```
public class StrategyObject
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "return the text to display";
    }
}


StrategyObject selectedStratObj = comboBox1.SelectedItem as StrategyObject;
```

Comment: Should the data class really know about how it is presented?  This seems like a violation of SoC...

Comment: @GordonG: Well it depends how your StrategyObject is structured. Per example, if you had a collection of Animal and the class Animal has a property Name. It would be perfectly valid to return the property Name in the method ToString(). Now, If you need to generate a valid name for your object, my solution is not really the best for you.

Comment: But it's a nifty idea, and one I will remember for the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of my finest innovations. :) I'm really proud of this little one.

```
public class Stringable<T>
{
    private T _obj;
    private Func<T, string> _convertFn;

    public Stringable(T obj, Func<T, string> convertFn)
    {
        _obj = obj;
        _convertFn = convertFn;
    }

    public T GetObj() { return _obj; }
    public override string ToString() { return _convertFn(_obj); }
}
```

This generic class adds ToString() to any class (even a black-box class) and you can define its behavior inside the lambda. Imagine you have a class Person with properties FirstName and LastName. Here's how you would use it to populate Combo box.

```
_cboPersons.Items.Add(new Stringable<Person>(person,o=>string.Format("{0}, {1}", o.LastName, o.FirstName)));
```

Then, when combo box item is selected just use this to get the original object from your combo

```
Person person=(_cboPersons.SelectedItem as Stringable<Person>).GetObj() // Get's person object.
```